# how to center a title in a table cell

Tags: html, text, cell, center

how to center the

I would like to center the text "Information". Tried the align="center" but didn't work

Is my code correct?

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
    <th>column1</th>
    <th>column2</th>
    <th bgcolor="#4F81BD"><strong><font size="5" color="white" face="calibri" align="center">Information</font><strong></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

[EDIT] Here is the code I have built thanks to your answsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>Title</title>

<style type="text/css">
.centerText{
       text-align: center;}
</style>

</head>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th class="centerText" bgcolor="#4F81BD"><strong><font size="5" color="white" face="calibri" >Information</font><strong></th>
  </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is this the right way to handle this?

Comment: what browser are you testing on? it seems to work fine.

Comment: @AidanO: it didn't work in Firefox for example

Comment: Note to close voters > from the webmasters faq: `Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow. We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect entire websites.` I think it better stay here

Comment: @AidanO: I'm using firefox 8.0.1

Comment: @JMax: I'm in stackoverflow. I don't understand what you meant?

Comment: @tintincutes: this comment wasn't intended to you but to users who voted to migrate your question (see [the close privilege description](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)). You can see a similar dialog when you click on the flag link (you can have a try but don't validate, no need to bother moderators, they have enough stuff to handle) - I hope I have made myself clear enough (EDIT) Note that you can [see close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes) when rep>250

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you putting `align="center"` to the `font` tag inside of the `strong`. All of these elements are inline and doesn't fits all the cell width. To align it on center you need to put such attribute to the `th` tag or change displaying of the `string` and `font` tags to `display:block` to fit all the width.

The simplest way to do this is in CSS:

```
 table tr th { text-align:center; }
```

P.S. Better way is to move all of your inline style to CSS files.

Comment: yes it looks ok too. But another problem I got is when I add an image on the 2nd column. The text is below the image. What is the command that would make the text start from the top in line with the image. If you look at here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/100/25972118.png/, you can see the text is almost below the image.

Comment: Set css style `float:left` to your image and it will works in your case.

Comment: Do I need to declare this as a  class inside css stylesheet?

Comment: Keep all CSS style inside of stylesheets is good approach. From my point of view - yes, place it to stylesheet and use classes on the images if needed.

Comment: This is the code for the image.<img src="http://website.com/_logo.gif" alt="logo" /> If I create a class in the css, let's say .myimage {float:left;} where shall I insert the .myimage? Can I write it like this: <img class=myiamge src="http://website.com/_logo.gif" alt="logo" />

Comment: Yes, you can. And don't forget about quotes: `<img class="myimage" src="website.com/_logo.gif"; alt="logo" />`

Comment: That's cool:-) It works, thanks But the problem is the text is too near with the image. Not sure if I have to indent within the font, is it text-indent?

Comment: Thanks I think I solved it. its <img class="myimage" src="http://website.com/logo.gif" alt="logo" style="margin-right:10px;" />

Answer (score 2):

Try using CSS.

```
table th {text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align:center;`

see this [live example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsscam/q3M4R/1/)

[EDIT] Note that you should implement these styles within your CSS with classes or elements as pointed out by fellow users

Comment: Yes it is. You shouldn't edit your post this way because it is harder to follow for any fellow users. Yet, your code seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for checking the code. Hmm how will I edit my post then? Do I have to open another question form for this?

Comment: No. I've edited your question to show you the way *I would* have handled this for better readibility

Answer (score 1):

1. The `<font>` tag [is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#graphics-fonts) and it's use is considered a very bad idea. Use CSS instead.
2. Using the `<strong>` tag just to get the text to be bold is also not particularly useful, especially inside a `<th>` element. The `<th>` already indicates that the text matters because it's the header of a table column. In many browsers, the text is already made bold in `<th>`s
3. The CSS style used to center the text is: `text-align: center`

Comment: No, you are still using the `<font>` tag, and using the `<strong>` tag where it isn't needed. What you have will center the text, but the code you have is poor quality overall.

Comment: Not sure how to do this. Do you mean I have to define the font size, the font color in the center text in my style sheet css?

Comment: Is this what you mean: .centerText{
          text-align: center;
    font-size:6;
    color:white;
    font-family:calibri;}

Comment: Thank you. I'm just wondering because, if I put the font-size=5; it will not change, but if I use the % and the one from your example the size changes. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: The reason is because you need to specify the units. I would _highly_ suggest getting a book on CSS and reading a bit. Learning a technology before you use it is usually a good time investment because you will spend less time flailing about trying to solve "problems" that you have because you don't quite know what you are doing.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Do you have any recommendation where I can read about CSS online? I found some of these sites: http://www.w3schools.com/css/ & http://cssdesk.com/ & http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/ but this one is too robust for me...

Comment: The w3schools site is an _ok_ starting point and will get your feet wet with CSS. There are _lots_ of others out there, but none that I have used recently.

Answer (score -1):

Trying this

```
<th bgcolor="#4F81BD" align="center"><strong><font size="5" color="white" face="calibri" >Information</font><strong></th>
```

Comment: Please _never_ suggest that someone _continue_ to use deprecated HTML elements and put stylistic attributes on HTML tags. Doing so makes the web an uglier place.